# Can i link google maps from within my application without paying fees?

Tags: delphi, google-maps

When i use the Google Maps API from within my commercial application, i have to sign-up for an API key and i have to pay fees for the usage of the Google Maps API.

What happens if i just use a link that opens a new browser window in my app?

Example:

http://maps.google.de/?saddr=Los_Angeles&daddr=hollywood

Do i have to pay fees for this, too?

Thanks in advance,

David

Comment: This is a question you really need to ask Google, SO is not a place to find ways to evade fees for using a third-party service.

Comment: Lazarus, I disagree, there will be SO users out there who may well know the details of the T&Cs and will be able to help TheJeed here.

Comment: @_J_: I disagree. This is a legal question, and since SO isn't a legal support forum, any advice you get is worth exactly what you pay for it. Since legal issues can get you sued, and being sued can cost you $$$, any legal questions should be answered by someone qualified to answer them.

Answer (score 4):

No you do not have to pay for such usage.

In addition, using the Google Maps API can also be free, if your Maps API implementation is generally accessible to users without charge. ([Google Maps API Terms of Service](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/terms.html))

Comment: And I think that's the important detail there.  Generally accessible to users without charge.  But if this is a commercial app that's charging money, then it's reasonable to pay some of that income to support the service that helps bring the money in, no?

Comment: It sends an interesting signal, to want to use something someone else puts out there for free, and then want users to pay for your bits.  :-)

Comment: @Mason: I agree with you. Apart from the reasonable fairness, a commercial application may require a premier license for many other benefits, such as an SLA, HTTPS support, control over adverts, geocoding limits, etc. More info from: http://www.google.com/enterprise/earthmaps/maps.html.

Comment: 'generally accessible' means 'public' (see section 9.1 of the Google Maps API Terms of Service). It must not operate only behind a firewall.